# creating a normally distributed matrix in numpy with specified mean and variance per element

Tags: python, numpy

Assume 3 matrices Mean, Variance, Sample all with the same dimensionality. Is there a 1 line solution to generate the Sample matrix in numpy such that:

```
 Sample[i,j] is drawn from NormalDistribution(Mean[i,j], Variance[i,j])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linearity of mean and Var(aX +b) = a**2 Var(X):

Generate a centered and reduced 2D array with `np.random.randn()`. Multiply pointwise by std (np.sqrt(variance)) and add (still pointwise) mean.

Comment: Completely forgot about the transformation between a standard normal and a normal distribution. Great!